# Nested Component react.cloneElement with react-form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to fix a problem with this library : [react-form](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-form). 
For information, this is my current error :

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `CustomInput`.

This is what i'm trying to do :

```js
<CustomInput field="date" showErrors={false}>
    <DatePickerForm />
</CustomInput>
```

this is my CustomInput Component :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormInput from 'react-form';

class CustomInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const { showErrors, field, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <FormInput showErrors={showErrors} field={field}>
        {({ setValue }) => {
          return (
            React.cloneElement(children, { setValueForm: setValue })
          );
        }}
      </FormInput>
    );
  }
}
export default CustomInput;
```

React.cloneElement(children, { setValueForm: setValue }) seems to return an object. 
But if i just render React.cloneElement without "FormInput" part, the rendering is ok. 
So, i suppose the problem come from the function of FormInput.

What do i make wrong ?

you can check the [FormInput class](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-form/blob/master/src/formInput.js)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: @Dekel it's very complicated to explain by writing ^^. My final point is : i don't want to write in each component (that uses form), "<FormInput>blablabla</FormInput>" ... i would prefer just have <customInput> way. More readable firstly.
Secondly, in each child component of FormInput (in this example : datepicker) , i need to set a default value for each field of the current form. So, instead, every time, write this, i'm trying to have a more readable big form components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're importing wrong: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form#-forminput-

```
import { FormInput } from "react-form"
```

as opposed to

```
import FormInput from "react-form"
```

Comment: Oooh boy, right ! I feel so stupid ... after some hours to find why it's not working !!!

Comment: Yep, seems to be good, but it's late, i'm going to try tomorrow morning with a fresh head ^^ , i come back it it worked ^^